# desktop files and Ubuntu software Center

Tags: 12.04, launcher, software-center, unity

Since 12.04, when additional software is installed, Ubuntu software center puts an icon in the launcher, representing a .desktop file in `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/`. This desktop file is not "overruled" by a (possible) local .desktop file in `~.local/share/applications`.

My question is:
Why is the initial icon (.desktop file) put there, and is not the default .desktop file used that is located in `/usr/share/applications`?

Comment: BTW; I do not see a file corresponding to my app in either of the locations that you mention.

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean; is "my app" an application installed by the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: Yes - "my app" is an application we are developing and packaged with Debian that is then installed using the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: @ Danny That is interesting, because then I wonder where and why the decission is taken. There might be a good reason for it, but I do not know it. It was a problem to me, in developping a quicklist editor, that edited the "usual" local desktop file. That would normally overrule the default desktop file, but not the one I described in my post. In the meantime I found a workaround to edit the gsettings and remove the initial icon (if it exists) and replace it by the edited one in the same index.

Comment: @JacobVlijm What about http://askubuntu.com/a/470336/256099 ?

Comment: @Pandya Now that is excellent information. The procedure to link the initial icon in the launcher to the desktop file in `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/` seems to be left behind us, which is good news for me; it made things more complicated for a quicklist editor.

Comment: @JacobVlijm , This is old, did you get you needed answer from the post pointed by Pandya? Or still looking for reason?

Comment: @Sneetsher thanks for noticing! The linked answer is satisfying enough to mark this question as a dupe :)

Answer (score 0):

Because that is how Ubuntu was designed. When you install an app from Ubuntu Software Center, Ubuntu puts an icon for only the user who installed the app.

Comment: ...but that is not a reason to use a .desktop file in a different location, as the (local) contents of the launcher is determined in the gsettings.