# What are possible directories for .desktop files and their icons, and when to use what directory?

Tags: launcher, icons, .desktop

Here are some of the directories where `.desktop` files describing applications can be found:

```
~/local/.share/applications
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/app-install/desktop
```

Perhaps there are even more of them. What is the actual purpose of every particular one to exist and into which should I put my application .desktop file in what a case?

And where are application icons put to be found as referenced in the `.desktop` files?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @JacobVlijm. AI have had no time to check it thoroughly (if there are no other places) so far but it seems legit.

Comment: Probably a typo. Try `~/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### .desktop files

*Globally* installed applications have their `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`. *If* a similarly named `.desktop` file exists in `~/.local/share/applications`, it will "overrule" the global one (after log out/in after they were created). Local `.desktop` files are used for user-specific alterations of the functionality of the launcher, to add items to the quicklist (in Unity) e.g., *or* for locally installed applications.

The third directory you mention, `/usr/share/app-install/desktop` is used by `Software Center`, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/470336/72216). Many applications don't use this one at all.

#### Icons

can technically be stored anywhere. Small applications can have their files (including icon) e.g. stored in one self-containing directory in `/opt/<application_name>`, but most of them will be found in `/usr/share/icons/`. 
An excellent Question/Answer(s) combination on icons can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435603/desktop-files-how-to-specify-the-icon-path).